# Difference between Case and Employee Cases

Tags: case, administration, employee-community

We're using employee licenses which are basically App Cloud Lightning 100 license but limited to 10 objects and they use employee cases as opposed to regular cases.

I've been searching for the difference between the 2 and I'm uncertain as to what the differences are.

Any ideas?

Comment: I believe `Case` is for external cases, `EmployeeCase` is for internal cases. If a customer has a problem, it could go into `Case`, if an colleague's Computer is running slow,  it'd be an employee case. I think that's the difference, but I'm not 100%.

Comment: I think we lose web-to-case but I'm not sure if there are other CRUD limitations or permission limitations.  I have about 17 licenses to play with so I'm setting up a sandbox now

Comment: I expect you're right. I imagine the object has limitations (e.g. API) in place for things exactly like that, but I'd expect you to be able to perform DML on the object from native Apex. Either way, that is indeed the difference.

Answer (score 1):

I left a comment but I may as well write it as an answer. `Case` is for external cases (e.g. Customer's product is faulty), `EmployeeCase` for colleagues who's computer is running slow or who's Salesforce App isn't working right.

From the [pricing and editions page:](http://www.salesforce.com/uk/crm/editions-pricing-communities.jsp)

> - Cases for Employee Apps & Community limited to internal operations and employees. Not to be used for customer cases.

Comment: Think about the sharing model too, the manager might need to see an employee's case, but not other employees (imagine HR or payroll cases).